# How can I stop this slide in menu from scrolling to the top of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On [this website](https://formever.com) that I'm developing, if you scroll down, the header collapses. To access the navigation menu when the header is compressed, you press the "hamburger" icon on the top left:

[image: Navigation access icon]

The navigation menu slides in as it should, but one problem I'm having is that clicking the icon also returns the page to the top, which is not the desired behaviour:

[image: Menu visible, page at top]

I'd like to stop the page scrolling to the top when the slide-in menu is activated, but I can't figure out how to do that. I am using jQuery, and I read that if I implement the command `e.preventDefault()` then it might prevent the page from scrolling, but I'm not sure where to implement that command. It doesn't work if I put it directly in the `href` element like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="e.preventDefault();" class="nav-toggler toggle-push-left fa fa-bars"></a>
```

A solution doesn't have to involve jQuery, though. I'm open to any approach. **How do I get the side menu to slide in but not return the page to the top?**

This is the Javascript that drives the menu, which I got online, so I don't necessarily understand all of it:

```
(function( window ){

    'use strict';

    var body = document.body,
        mask = document.createElement("div"),
        togglePushLeft = document.querySelector( ".toggle-push-left" ),
//      pushMenuLeft = document.querySelector( ".push-menu-left" ),
        activeNav
    ;
    mask.className = "mask";

    /* push menu left */
    togglePushLeft.addEventListener( "click", function(){
        classie.add( body, "pml-open" );
        document.body.appendChild(mask);
        activeNav = "pml-open";
    } );

    /* hide active menu if mask is clicked */
    mask.addEventListener( "click", function(){
        classie.remove( body, activeNav );
        activeNav = "";
        document.body.removeChild(mask);
    } );

    /* hide active menu if close menu button is clicked */
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close-menu")).forEach(function(el,i){
        el.addEventListener( "click", function(){
            classie.remove( body, activeNav );
            activeNav = "";
            document.body.removeChild(mask);
        } );
    });

    document.addEventListener( "keyup", function(e) {
        if ( parseInt(e.keyCode) === 27 && classie.has( body, activeNav ) ) {
            classie.remove( body, activeNav );
            document.body.removeChild(mask);
        }
    });

})( window );
```

This is the `classie.js` that is referenced above:

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
  // CommonJS
  module.exports = classie;
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: i try to click on that hamburger icon but it did not push me on top in mobile view..issue only occur in desktop version.

Comment: There are multiple references to `classie`. Where is it defined?

Comment: m not having much access to your code but try to remove  $('#nav-toggler').css('display', 'block'); this css style from  header.js and this also $('#nav-toggler').css('display', '') ... m just saying for purpost. just test once and let me know what happen

Comment: @JonStødle, sorry, I should have included the `classie.js` file as well. It's now in the question.

Comment: @Leothelion, yes, it appears you're right. Any idea as to why the effect would work correctly on a mobile device but not a desktop browser? I'd like to ensure the behaviour is the same on both.

Comment: @Dave Can you try: `togglePushLeft.addEventListener( "click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* rest of the code here */ });`?

Comment: What about making the position of the nav bar as fixed? (CSS property) so the nav bat will overlap and will not push the other block.

Comment: @Dave did you remove that lines which i said? and test after that..it might work.

Comment: @AbraarArique, that worked! Thank you. Please put that as an answer so I can mark your solution as correct. `:)` Also note that I put it in every instance where ` "click", function()` appeared in the code so that the page would also not scroll to the top when closing the side menu.

Comment: @Dave Awesome, I've put my solution as an answer bellow. Your question was very good, so I gave a +1 vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using `e.preventDefault()` will work, but you can't use it inline like `onclick="e.preventDefault();"`. The `e` is actually the event object that fires upon event trigger, so the correct syntax is:

```
$("selector").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

As the hamburger link contains `href="#"`, by clicking it it'll move to the top. So we use `preventDefault()` to stop (or "prevent") it.

**Replace your code with:**

```
(function( window ){

    'use strict';

    var body = document.body,
        mask = document.createElement("div"),
        togglePushLeft = document.querySelector( ".toggle-push-left" ),
//      pushMenuLeft = document.querySelector( ".push-menu-left" ),
        activeNav
    ;
    mask.className = "mask";

    /* push menu left */
    togglePushLeft.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        classie.add( body, "pml-open" );
        document.body.appendChild(mask);
        activeNav = "pml-open";
    } );

    /* hide active menu if mask is clicked */
    mask.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        classie.remove( body, activeNav );
        activeNav = "";
        document.body.removeChild(mask);
    } );

    /* hide active menu if close menu button is clicked */
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close-menu")).forEach(function(el,i){
        el.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            classie.remove( body, activeNav );
            activeNav = "";
            document.body.removeChild(mask);
        } );
    });

    document.addEventListener( "keyup", function(e) {
        if ( parseInt(e.keyCode) === 27 && classie.has( body, activeNav ) ) {
            classie.remove( body, activeNav );
            document.body.removeChild(mask);
        }
    });

})( window );
```

Hope that answers your question.